# How to config Spyder to work with a large file

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

I have a large data frame in Pandas, python. How can I config and increase default value in Spyder to load this file into memory and processs. In Pycharm: we can open VMoption and change the default value to -xmx 4g. How can I do the same thing for Spyder?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) That's not something Spyder handles, it depends on the RAM memory available in your computer.

Comment: Also, you should look at the [Dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) project to see how to handle big Dataframes.

Comment: I edited the question. Thank for your feedback

Comment: Ok, thanks. Unfortunately, we don't have such an option in Spyder and I don't understand what it does.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba `-Xmx 4g` is a [Java virtual machine option](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/tuning-the-ide.html).

Comment: What error or incorrect behaviour do you see when you try to load this data at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no such option in Spyder, sorry.